# Use PDFMaker with MS Outlook

Tags: vba, pdf, outlook

i want to use the Adobe PDFMaker add-in with MS Outlook 2013.

[Saving multiple e-mails to pdf with PDFMAKER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723984/saving-multiple-e-mails-to-pdf-with-pdfmaker/51400870#51400870)

I've seen this post and tried the code, but i get an runtime-error 13 (type mismatch) at the line

```
Set pmkr2 = a.Object
```

It seems like the object coming from a.Object is not an PDFMaker object. [See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5yXw.png)
I am using Adobe Acrobat DC 18.2816.
Here is my whole code:

```
    Sub ConvertToPDFWithLinks()
   Dim pmkr2 As AdobePDFMakerForOffice.PDFMaker
   'Set pmkr2 = Application.COMAddIns.Item(6).Object ' Assign object reference.
   Set pmkr2 = Nothing

   For Each a In Application.COMAddIns
      If InStr(UCase(a.Description), "PDFMAKER") > 0 Then
        Set pmkr2 = a.Object
        Exit For
      End If
   Next

   If pmkr2 Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "Cannot Find PDFMaker add-in", vbOKOnly, ""
      Exit Sub
   End If

   Dim pdfname As String
   pdfname = "C:\stuff\stuff\tester.pdf"

   Dim stng As AdobePDFMakerForOffice.ISettings
   pmkr2.GetCurrentConversionSettings stng

   stng.AddBookmarks = True
   stng.AddLinks = True
   stng.AddTags = True
   stng.ConvertAllPages = True
   stng.CreateFootnoteLinks = True
   stng.CreateXrefLinks = True
   stng.OutputPDFFileName = pdfname
   stng.PromptForPDFFilename = False
   stng.ShouldShowProgressDialog = True
   stng.ViewPDFFile = False

   pmkr2.CreatePDFEx stng, 0

   Set pmkr2 = Nothing ' Discontinue association.
End Sub
```

It would be very nice if someone would be able to help me, thank you in advance!

Comment: "Object" appears to be incorrect `Set pmkr2 = a`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but im still getting the same error. The types of the objects still dont match, pmkr2 is of the type PDFMaker and a of the type Variant/Object/COMAddin

Answer (score 0):

Try being less specific in the declaration.

```
Sub getAnObject()

    Dim pmkr2 As Object
    Dim a As Object
    Dim srchString As String

    srchString = "PDFMAKER"

    Set pmkr2 = Nothing

    For Each a In Application.COMAddIns

        Debug.Print "a.Description: " & a.Description

        If InStr(UCase(a.Description), srchString) > 0 Then

            If MsgBox("Is this what you want? " & vbCr & vbCr & a.Description, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
                Set pmkr2 = a
                Exit For
            End If

        End If

    Next

    If pmkr2 Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Cannot find the object using search string " & srchString
    Else
        Debug.Print "Object found: " & pmkr2.Description
    End If

    Set pmkr2 = Nothing ' Discontinue association.

End Sub
```

Comment: It still doesnt work! I wasnt able to test it untill today, but now i tested it and i got an runtime error 438 (Object doesn't support this property or method) at the line `pmkr2.GetCurrentConversionSettings stng`

Comment: The runtime-error 13 (type mismatch) is as far as I can go without that add-in. You could try a new question describing the current different problem.